# How to hide sidebar when screen too small? Without framework

Tags: html, css

My sidebar html looks like this:

```
<div id="sidenav">
    <img id="logo" src="Images/Logo.png">
    <a href="#first">
        <p>Home</p>
    </a>
    <a href="#second">
        <p>What?</p>
    </a>
    <a href="#third">
        <p>Who?</p>
    </a>
    <a href="#fourth">
        <p>Contact</p>
    </a>
</div>
```

And the css:

```
#sidenav {
height: 100%;
width: 280px;
position: fixed;
z-index: 1;
top: 0;
left: 0;
background-color: white;
overflow-x: hidden;
transition: 0.5s;
padding-top: 10px;
transition: all 300ms ease 0s;
}

#sidenav a {
padding: 0px 0px 0px 32px;
margin: 0px;
text-decoration: none;
color: #0e1c2c;
display: block;
transition: 0.3s
}

#sidenav a:hover {
color: #ea4e3c;
}
```

My idea was to use this:

```
@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
#sidenav {
    display: none;
}
```

But it wasn't working.

My end goal is to remove the sidebar completely when people are viewing on mobile, then maybe add another container at the top of the page with the logo in. This way there's a lot more room for the page to breathe since it's just a 100% width container, above another, above another. Is it possible just to make the changes to the CSS and html you want within an @media bracket? 
Any help appreciated!

Comment: 1) Define "wasn't working". 2) If you have a side bar, wouldn't you want `max-width`? 3) Do you have that meta tag that allows for media queries in CSS?

Comment: meta tag with html5 doctype required before proceeding towards media queries

Comment: you need to use `max-width` for your media query not `max-height`

Comment: The media tag is in my CSS. By not working I mean the sidenav is still being displayed. And it sounds like I've misunderstood how to use the @media.

Comment: I don't think you understand what `max-height` is a height for. Its not the height of the phones screen... its the height of your `<html>` document, which will vary from page to page

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have the right idea, but there are a couple things that need to be changed. Instead of using `max-height` it would be better to use `max-width`. Usually, 768px is considered the breakpoint for mobile width vs. desktop width (remember that users can turn their phones sideways and that there are some large phones). Also, there was a missing curly brace. If you change all of that, you will end up with this:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    #sidenav {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Comment: display: none  !important ;

Answer (score 1):

```
@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
 #sidenav { 
display: none;
 }
}
```

The only problem that can be seen in your code is that you didn't close the first curly brace.

Also, add the below tag in the `head` of your page

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

This makes the browser render the width of the page at the width of its screen.

Comment: I would not recommend using `max-height` for a media query. Very bad idea

Comment: Me too use max-width. But here OP says that he want to use max-height. Thats why I answered it using max-height